# About McAfee Total Protection 200X

Tags: anti-virus

i just want to ask if McAfee Total Protection needs SDAT's like the other versions before? I'm thinking if I should try out this version. And what are your comments on this Anti-virus.

Answer (score 1):

From their [FAQ](http://www.mcafeeasap.com/MarketingContent/Products/TopsFAQ.aspx):

> **What types of updates does the Total
>   Protection Service automatically
>   provide?**
>
> An update may contain one or more of the following:
>
> - Daily virus definition (DAT) files: Signatures for existing and new
>     viruses and new security-risked
>     spyware.
> - Agent updates: Software changes to address a known issue or
>     add a new scanning feature.
> - Policy changes: Custom policies that apply to a group of
>     computers (for example, scheduling an
>     on-demand scan).

So I suppose the answer to your question is **Yes, it still needs DAT files**.

BTW, I suppose you mean DAT-files in stead of SDAT's? (SDAT stands for SuperDAT which is actually the utility that updates the DAT files.)

I cannot really comment on this new product, as I haven't used it before (Actually this post brought it to my attention ;-).
I do know standard McAfee crap-ware (I have to deal with its inefficiencies on a daily basis). And as a general rule of thumb: there's only one anti-virus software that is worse than McAfee's, and that's Norton's (IMHO).

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative reply! :D Instead of arguing with me that i want a discussion. ^_^ Well..i agree with you there, i nver liked norton! Since 8 years ago!!

Although, have you tried Microsoft's Anti-virus?

Comment: @Midori: You're welcome :) and nope, I haven't tried Microsoft's anti-virus. I'm actually quite anti-anti-virus ;-) Here at work I have no choice. McAfee is mandatory. If one would force me to install something at home, it would be http://www.clamwin.com/.

Comment: @Midori: see also http://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows (feel free to upvote me btw ;-)